# Serve dynamically generated image or saved image with Express

Tags: javascript, express, sharp

I built an image delivery app which can serve images and resize/change image extension on-demand.

I use Express for the routing and Sharp to work on the images.

When an image is requested with a new size/extension, I want to save the generated image on the filesystem and retrieve the saved image the next time the same image is requested with the same parameters (sort of a cache).

Everything I built is working fine, but in production CPU usage is high. I suspect it is because I return an image with `res.sendFile()` after saving it on the filesystem.

At the moment here is my workflow :

- I check on the filesystem if the image is already saved with the wanted parameters (`fs.access()`)
- If it exists, I `res.sendFile` the local image path
- If it doesn't exist, I generate it using Sharp, I save it on the filesystem and I `res.sendFile` the generated image path

I read `res.sendFile` doesn't use the system sendfile call, and is CPU-heavy.

How can I replace it ?

Here is what I found when googling :

- When I generate a new image, I can `res.send()` the buffer generated by Sharp instead of `res.sendFile` the saved image
- When the image is already saved, maybe I should use the static express middleware (http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) but I don't know how I can dynamically call it and tell it the image path (based on the parameters provided in the request URL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `static` middleware will unfortunately yield the same performance characteristics since it's using the same methods under the hood as `res.sendFile`. It seems like what you want to do is to serve the images from Nginx or a similar reverse proxy running in front of your app.

There are a few ways to accomplish this. The easiest is probably to send out redirects from your Node.js app that points to a location that the reverse proxy will serve.

Basically, when a request comes in for `/imageID/toto.jpg?quality=80`, you want to redirect that to `/static-images/imageID_80.jpg`.

```
// ...

const imageName = ${req.params.imageId}_${req.query.quality}.jpg

if (!(await pathExists(imageName))) {
  await generateFileUsingSharp(req.params.imageId, req.query.quality)
}

res.redirect(`/static-images/${imageName}`)
```

Then you would let Nginx serve files under the `/static-images` location:

```
location /static-images {
  alias /var/www/generated-images;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems a solid option to me (I didn't even had to ask for code samples, it's very clear). One little other question on top of this one : I currently use fs.access to see if a path exists. I saw some use fs.stats, which do you think would be the most efficient ?

Comment: I would guess that `fs.access` is faster since it doesn't return all the (in this case) unrelated information. I personally use `path-exists` (https://github.com/sindresorhus/path-exists) which uses `fs.access` internally, but returns a `Promise`